# What happens when you cast a character that isn't on the ascii chart to type int in C++?

Tags: c++, casting, ascii

Does it have it's own value? Will certain characters crash the program?

Comment: Assuming `sizeof(char) < sizeof(int)`, the integer cast of a signed char or an unsigned char will retain the same value.

Answer (score 2):

With the assumption of `sizeof(char) < sizeof(int)`.  And for the example below, let's assume 32-bit integer and a 2's complete arch.

Casting a **signed char or an unsigned char** to a **signed integer** expression will result in the same value being promoted to int.

Casting an **unsigned char** to an **unsigned int** expression will result in the same value being promoted to unsigned int.

Casting a **signed char** to an **unsigned integer** expression might have slightly different behavior based on how you think of casting. The signed char will get promoted to signed integer first - which includes getting "signed extended" to retain any negative value.  Then casted to unsigned.

The latter case has an interesting side effect when casting and promoting negative values.

```
signed char c = 0x7f;  // 0x7f expressed as a signed char is 127
unsigned int n = c; // n gets 0x0000007f (127)


signed char c = 0xff;  // 0xff expressed as a signed char is -1
unsigned int n = c; // n gets 4294967295 (0xffffffff)
```

The reason why I explicitly call out "signed char" vs "unsigned char" above is because this variable:

```
char c;
```

Could be signed or unsigned depending on how the compiler decides to treat it. Most compilers default to signed, but have a compiler option to treat as unsigned.

I've had to fix a few bugs because code assumed the wrong sign-ness for char.

Comment: Conversion to unsigned integer and to signed integer that can represent the original value is defined and I don't think it may have different behavior if the compilers are good and no undefined behaviors are invoked. Please read [N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) 4.7 Integral conversions.

Comment: I tried casting an è to int and I think it converted it to the normal e ascii value, I don't want that

Comment: For the case of plain char being signed, you don't even need that sizeof assumption.  Also `signed char c = 0xff;` leads to `c` having an *implementation-defined* value.

Comment: "The signed char will get promoted to signed integer first" - this is false.  `unsigned int n = c;`  directly converts from `signed char` to `unsigned int` with no promotion or other intermediate steps.    Also, in the previous paragraph "promoted" should read "converted".